# TFS access denied to only one specific domain user

Tags: tfs, active-directory, connection, privileges

I created a local group user which I added to TFS Contributor/Valid User groups. Anytime if I needed to add a user as contributor, I would add him/her to the local group and the person has the access to TFS; which is until now. Recently a new person got hired and MIS setup the domain account for him. I added him the same way but for some reason he couldn't connect to TFS. I tried everything that I know of. I even asked MIS to recreate (delete and create again) the user in ADS. But nothing seems to be working. Does anybody know what could be possible problem?

Comment: How many users do you have on TFS (excluding the one that just got hired)?

Comment: 24. But I added two other new users too. And they have the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved the problem. It was TFS cache that was causing this problem. Once I cleared it, everything worked fine.

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that the a user did not get permission to TFS when adding hem/her to the user group. I resolved it by adding the user directly to TFS. You can use the TFS Administration Tool to add users quickly to TFS, SSRS and Sharepoint: http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com

Comment: OK.. I had also faced the same issue. I think this is also because of some caching. But the fix was easy. When you are using system local groups (Window groups) for grouping your users and adding them to TFS group, whenever you are refreshing the local group by adding new user or removing existing user, you need to remove the whole group from TFS and then add them again.